# Why does JS desctructuring assignment work with numbers

Tags: javascript, destructuring, language-features

As the title says, why does this code not throw a SyntaxError? I thought you could only destructure Objects

```js
const {
  a,
  b
} = 0;

console.log(a, b); // undefined, undefined
```

Comment: Why shouldn't it?

Comment: btw, syntax error can't be thrown, because it is not a runtime error that can be thrown during the application execution. If an exception is thrown, it means the code is syntactically correct and running.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you access a property of a primitive, the primitive's object wrapper is used to see if such a property exists on the prototype. For example, `Number.prototype.toFixed` exists. So you could theoretically do something like

```js
const {
  toFixed
} = 0;

console.log(toFixed);
```

or

```js
Number.prototype.a = 'foo'; // just for example, please never do this
Number.prototype.b = 'bar';

const {
  a,
  b
} = 0;

console.log(a, b);
```

It's not invalid syntax, it's just really weird.

Comment: Thank you, this makes perfect sense now that you mention it. Still really weird to see it in action...